# Rails 4 Ajax POST from console, strong params not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to post via AJAX. My `Formal` controller only has one field: `ids`.

I have the parameters white listed:

```
def formal_params
  params.require(:formal).permit(:ids)
end

json = {formal:{ids:["2134"]}}
$.ajax({
    url: '/formals/create',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'json',
    accept: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: json
    });
```

I've tried 100 variations on this and get a `param is missing or the value is empty: formal` every time.

What am I doing wrong? If it's a dumb mistake, please let me know. I'll add any information you need...and I know this may be a duplicate, but I've been pulling my hair out for hours. Please advise.

Comment: can you post what your `params` looks like right before the `params.require(:formal).permit(:ids)` ?

Comment: @Fer, what exactly do you want to see???

Comment: Got it....
`params.fetch(:formal, {}).permit(:ids, ids: [])`
This is way too complicated to find via google. Maybe someone can explain?

Comment: Funny how you can work on something all day, then have a moment of clarity hours later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ids` is an array, your strong parameters should look like this:

`params.require(:formal).permit(ids: [])`

From the [strong parameters docs](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values):

> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values map the key to an empty array:
>
> `params.permit(:id => [])`

Comment: Can't believe it was this easy. Thank you.